# iPod iOS 5.1.1 safe mode without any touchscreen controls

Tags: ipod, touchscreen

I have a safe mode issue with my iPod touch fourth gen. IOS: 5.1.1. It was working just fine for about a year and then the other day I installed a tweak that allowed for vertical scrolling of the home screen from HYI repo (I tried to install the same tweak a few months ago along with another tweak and I got booted into safe mode but everything worked fine in safe mode, so I went into Cydia and uninstalled the two tweaks thinking that they were conflicting with each other. After that I re-sprang it and it worked like normal.) and I got booted like normal but this time it froze on lock screen and then booted into safe mode. (o_O) THIS time my touch screen wouldn't work. So I forced re-booted it by holding the home and lock button until the screen flashed white and then showed the apple boot logo. After that I uninstalled the tweak and it worked fine. Today I just installed two add ons and upgraded HTML Widgets related to SB Settings. The other two add ons were iOS 7 ringtones and notification alert sounds. Yet again I was greeted by my usual lock screen pic and then the safe mode black picture lock screen, again, my touch screen wouldn't work but the buttons would. So I just re-booted it by holding the buttons thinking it would solve the problems, but of course, it did nothing to solve it... Now this time I am actually stuck in safe mode and do not want to restore my jailbreak because I have a bunch of tweaks and settings I worked really hard on.

PLEASE could SOMEONE fix this problem with the safe mode and SB Settings tweaks?! I am clueless with what to do. 
Thanks!